# Why am I getting this error when I try to slice a Zarr array exactly the same way I would slice a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, zarr

I am using the following code to slice a Zarr array from disk:

```
import zarr as zr

db = zr.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Share/Daily Data/Database/dbz.zarr', mode='r')
data = db[db[:,0]==20171003]
```

Here is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4ae364a8c3b1> in <module>()
      1 dbz_ranked = zr.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Share/Daily Data/Database/dbz_ranked.zarr', mode='w', shape=(8245164, 345),chunks=(100000, 345), dtype='float64')
----> 2   data = db[db[:,0]==20171003]


3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zarr/indexing.py in __init__(self, selection, array)
    280                 raise IndexError('unsupported selection item for basic indexing; '
    281                                  'expected integer or slice, got {!r}'
--> 282                                  .format(type(dim_sel)))
    283 
    284             dim_indexers.append(dim_indexer)

IndexError: unsupported selection item for basic indexing; expected integer or slice, got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I have no clue why this isn't working, I thought Zarr was supposed to slice just like a Numpy array?

Comment: "I thought Zarr was supposed to slice just like a Numpy array?" - the error message and the [docs](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#advanced-indexing) both say nope.

Comment: I have gone trhough that, still can't figure it out, do you have any idea?

Comment: `db[db[:,0]==20171003]` involves a slice for `db[:0]` but `db[<boolan array>]` is not a slice, it is considered "advanced" indexing, which apparently isn't supported by `zarray`... looks like you need to use `get_mask_selection`

Comment: I have get_mask_selection working but it returns its without the original shape... do you know how I can keep the original shape?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following page to be helpful: https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/core.html

In summary, using `zarr_array.oindex([])` allows classic indexing/slicing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).